# How to stop build process of storyboard in xcode?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode7

I have a project with some targets in Xcode. When I open the storyboard file, the project starts to build. It is a slow process...

How can I stop this build process when I open the storyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is a way you can avoid this behavior, open the storyboard in an active window, disable `"Automatically Refresh Views"` from the `Editor` menu. This will stop updating the views in the `storyboard` editor that use your custom code and thus speed up your development significantly. When you need again the just-in-time compiling to have a visual preview of your custom code, enable this option again (it seems you also have to re-open your storyboard to make it working again).

Comment: I wish I could give you 100 upvotes.  I have 4 targets and so each time I go to the storyboard it tries to build all 4.  With Xcode being so buggy much of the time the build process stalls out, causing all kinds of havoc and causing me to restart the app frequently.  THANK YOU! Buy that man a beer!